# Alternate method for deprecated "validates_associated" method in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

As you can see at http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated

This method has been deprecated.

I want to know the correct method that can be used in its place to validate associated models.

Thanks
Neelesh

Comment: `validates_associated` is gone in ActiveModel 4.0

Answer (score -1):

You could create your own method and callback.

```
class ShoppingCart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  before_validation :check_items

  def check_items
    items.each do |item|
      # check if valid and add to errors if any
    end
    return false if errors.any? # this will cause save to return false
  end
end
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: Assuming you are using ActiveRecord

Comment: This is something that will work. I want the vanilla way of "validates" http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates. I will use validates_associated till then.

Answer (score -1):

validates_associated is not deprecated. Do not trust apidock.com - it shows deprecation warnings for many things due to internal changes in Rails 2 and 3. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated

Comment: the question was about `ActiveModel`, not `ActiveRecord`